Order relation between spectral projections of positive operators in a Hilbert space
Let $ \mathcal{H} $ be a Hilbert space and $ \mathcal{B(H)} $ be the algebra of bounded operators on $ \mathcal{H} $. Let $ T $ and $ S $ be two distinct positive operators in $ \mathcal{B(H)} $ such that $ 0 \leq T \leq S $. For $ \mu > 0 $, let $ \chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(T) $ and $ \chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(S) $ denote the spectral projections associated with the intervals $ (\mu, \infty) $ for the operators $ T $ and $ S $, respectively.
I am interested in understanding the order relation between these spectral projections, particularly whether the inequality
$$
\chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(T) \leq \chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(S)
$$
holds in general when $ 0 \leq T \leq S $ and for all $ \mu > 0 $.
As an initial observation, consider the case where $ T $ and $ S $ are distinct non-zero projections. Suppose $ 0 < \mu < 1 $, in which case we have the following:
$$
\chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(T) = \chi_{\{1\}}(T) = T \quad \text{and} \quad \chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(S) = \chi_{\{1\}}(S) = S.
$$
In this scenario, we clearly have $ T \leq S $, and thus
$$
\chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(T) \leq \chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(S).
$$
My question is whether this inequality holds universally for all positive operators $ T $ and $ S $ satisfying $ T \leq S $, and for all $ \mu > 0 $, or if there exists a counterexample that would suggest otherwise.
I would greatly appreciate your insights or any references that could help clarify whether the inequality
$$
\chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(T) \leq \chi_{(\mu, \infty)}(S)
$$
holds in the general case, or if there are specific conditions under which it may fail. Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

In the case when $T$ and $S$ are projections, the condition $T\le S$ implies $ST=TS=T.$

A function $f\colon [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(S)\leq f(T)$ for all positive bounded operators $S$, $T$ with $S\leq T$ is called operator monotone. Operator monotone functions have been characterized by Löwner (Barry Simon has written a book about many proofs of this theorem). Every operator monotone function is smooth, which immediately rules out indicator functions.

What is true however is that if $f\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is monotone and measurable, then $0\leq S\leq T$ implies $\mathrm{tr}(f(S))\leq \mathrm{tr}(f(T))$. In the case of indicator functions, $\mathrm{tr}(f(S))$ counts the number of eigenvalues (with multiplicity) in a given set.

The claim holds if $T$ and $S$ are commuting. Otherwise it may fail. Indeed, let $$T= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1&1
\end{pmatrix}\quad\ S= \begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\ 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$ Then $T\le S.$ The eigenvalues of $T$ and $S$ are $0,2$ and  $ r_\pm={1\over 2}(3\pm \sqrt{5}),$ respectively. Let $r_{-}<\alpha <2.$ Then $\chi_{(\alpha,\infty)}(T)$ is the projection onto the eigenvector $(1,1)^t$ of $T$ corresponding to $2.$ On the other hand $\chi_{(\alpha,\infty)}(S)$ is the projection onto the eigenvector of $S$ corresponding to $r_+.$ These projections are not comparable, as $(1,1)^t$ is not an eigenvector of $T.$

Thank you for providing this example. Could you kindly offer some guidance or references for the proof in the commutative case?

This may be helpful
